# Is there a way to directly import data in R without reading file?

Tags: r

I am being a bit lazy here to make a csv file for the data I have and wanted to import this data directly in R console. This is a small tabular data and I wanted to test something real quick. Is there any option in R to read this directly in console?

```
Location    treatment   POX-C
Monmouth    CC  810.3024
Monmouth    CC  835.5242
Monmouth    CC  856.206
Monmouth    CC  759.8589
```

Comment: If not csv what so you mean then? txt? Where does data  come from?

Comment: @Christoph I mean I just don't want to use something like `read.delim`

Comment: Perhaps a minimal reproducible example would help.

Comment: `read.table(text=...)`

Comment: @Brian I think this would work

Comment: Copy the data to the clipboard and then enter: `DF <- read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE)`

Comment: Or `read.table(strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, text = readClipboard())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read.table` or `readr::read_table2` by just copying data into the script/console you're running:

```r
read.table(
text = "Location    treatment   POX-C
Monmouth    CC  810.3024
Monmouth    CC  835.5242
Monmouth    CC  856.206
Monmouth    CC  759.8589"
)
#>         V1        V2       V3
#> 1 Location treatment    POX-C
#> 2 Monmouth        CC 810.3024
#> 3 Monmouth        CC 835.5242
#> 4 Monmouth        CC  856.206
#> 5 Monmouth        CC 759.8589
readr::read_table2(
"Location    treatment   POX-C
Monmouth    CC  810.3024
Monmouth    CC  835.5242
Monmouth    CC  856.206
Monmouth    CC  759.8589"
)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Location treatment `POX-C`
#>   <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 Monmouth CC           810.
#> 2 Monmouth CC           836.
#> 3 Monmouth CC           856.
#> 4 Monmouth CC           760.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>